# Variable is concatenating, not incrementing in BASH

Tags: bash, variables, integer, typing

Here is the code:

```
v=0
for var in "$@";do
        echo $var
        v+=1
        echo $v
done
```

Here is the command:

```
$ bash MyScript.sh duck duck goose
```

Here is the output:

```
duck
01
duck
011
goose
0111
```

So it appears (to me) to be treating the variable v as a string or not an integer. I am not sure why it would do this and I feel like this is a simple issue that I am just overlooking one small detail.

Is this an example of the pitfalls of non-static typing?

Thanks,

Comment: short form: strings are the default type for *everything* in bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a math context to perform math. The bash-specific syntax for this is `(( ))`:

```
(( v += 1 )) # not POSIX compliant, not portable
```

Alternately, a POSIX-compliant syntax for a math context is `$(( ))`:

```
v=$(( v + 1 )) # POSIX-compliant!
```

...or...

```
: $(( v += 1 )) # POSIX-compliant!
```

There's also the non-POSIX-compliant `let` operation:

```
let v+=1 # not POSIX compliant, not portable, don't do this
```

...and the similarly non-POSIX-compliant `declare -i`:

```
declare -i v # not POSIX compliant, not portable, don't do this
             # ...also makes it harder to read or reuse snippets of your code
             # ...by putting action and effect potentially further from each other.
v+=1
```

Comment: Completely forgot about those thanks! Thanks for catching the title. My autocorrect guessed wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Bash doesn't do that. You have to use the mathematical operation syntax `$((...))`, viz:

```
v=0
for var in "$@";do
    echo $var
    v=$((v+1))
    echo $v
one
```

Output of `bash <file> duck duck duck goose`:

```
duck
1
duck
2
duck
3
goose
4
```

Comment: btw, `for var in "$@"; do` could also be written as `for var; do`.

Answer (score 0):

just add `typeset -i v` to your shell:

example:

```
typeset -i v
v=12
v+=1
echo $v
```

gives

```
13
```

Comment: This works, but I wouldn't exactly call it good practice: It makes your code harder to read, because one has to know the context to know how to interpret it.

Comment: Also, unlike `$(( ))`, this is a bashism, and won't work on all POSIX shells.